# how to create collection of array in php?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to create a colletion array .I use laravel in this case everything work , the route, the controller etc, the unique problem is that I need to the result have to similar to image

[image]

I try this code but dont works

```
$contacto_x_agendamientos = Contacto_x_Agendamiento::all();   
  $array = array( 
  foreach ($contacto_x_agendamientos as $contacto_x_agendamiento) {
     $array_2 = array(
         'id_contacto_agendamiento' =>$contacto_x_agendamiento->id_contacto_x_agendamiento
       );
   }
);
return response()->json($contacto_x_agendamientos->toArray());
```

I hope your help

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what?

Comment: Clean up the formatting of your code so that we can read it. Explain exactly what you're doing and what your output is. Then people will be happy to help and answer.

Comment: Why yes, starting a `foreach()` loop inside of an array is definitely going to cause issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [] shortcut

```
foreach ($contacto_x_agendamientos as $contacto_x_agendamiento) {
  $array_2[] = [
     'id_contacto_agendamiento' =>$contacto_x_agendamiento->id_contacto_x_agendamiento
  ];
}
```

in this way you popolate $array_2 with an array for each iteration

Comment: thanks you for you response, this work for me. but can you explain , why  put shorcut ? because if i dont use shorcut only create one array .

Comment: is just a comment  .. $array[]  =  ..  is introduced  some version ago in PHP for let the array declaration and poulation more easy  and now is commonly used  insetad of explicit and verose array(...)  ..declaration  http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php  ... https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays